# Plural or singular after a number?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, grammaticality, grammatical-number

Which one of those is correct grammatically? I

> We evaluate 1000 student result

Or

> We evaluate 1000 student results

Or

> We evaluate 1000 students' results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike some languages, nouns after a number other than 1 are plural in English - even after 0 and 0.5.

The distinction between *student results* and *students' results* is a different question. Both are valid, and in most contexts there is no practical difference in meaning (though there could be in some cases). The first is a compound noun phrase, with *student* (usually in the singular) as a modifier. The second is a possessive construction.

Comment: I totally agree. The last sentence does, to me, seem to be the most stylistically graceful. It's also very clear.

Comment: What about "Settlers of Catan is a three-player game"? is that correct? do I need the hyphen?

Comment: @JohannesWentu: it's fine, and most people would use the hyphen (though personally I'm not interested in discussions about the branch of fashion called punctuation). But please don't pose unrelated questions in the comments: if you have a question, raise it as a question.

Comment: why is it unrelated? three is a number and I'd like to know if after that I need to write the singular or the plural of a noun. in my language, we would write "three players" because plural means "more than one" and three is definitely more than one. This is why I am asking in a thread called "Plural or singular after a number?". I don't understand your request.

Comment: I thought it was unrelated because you are asking about the modifier "three-player". There was no such construction in your original question. But I can see that if in your language such modifiers take plural inflection, it might not look like a different case to you.